# error using makefile, targets and %

Tags: makefile, target

I'm trying to debug the following code:

```
TESTS=$(shell cat yoursourcefile)
all: $(TESTS)

%: compile_design
compile $@_tb.vhd >> log_file.log
simulate $@
```

I got this error:

```
makefile_tb.vhd >> log_file.log
```

as if makefile is a target

this error disappears when I add a character or more before %:

```
T%: compile_design
compile $@_tb.vhd >> log_file.log
simulate $@
```

This works but implies that all my targets starts with "T" which is not always the case.
My questions are:
what's exactly the function of % here ?
How to get rid of this error?

As suggested, I added

```
makefile: ; $@:
```

at the end, so I have now:

```
TESTS=$(shell cat yoursourcefile) 
all: $(TESTS)

%: compile_design 
compile $@_tb.vhd >> log_file.log
simulate $@

makefile: ; $@:
```

then when I do:

```
make all
```

I get [all] error2 all_tb.vhd >> log_file.log

but all_tb.vhd does not exist !

Answer (score 1):

The `%: compile_design` rule is a ["match-anything" pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Match_002dAnything-Rules.html).  It says "hey make, if you ever want to build *any* file, with any  name, then you can do it by running these commands.  Oh and by the way, if you have a file you want to build and it's older than the `compile_design` file, then you need to rebuild it".  Generally you want to avoid match-anything rules, but if your target names truly have no specific pattern, you can't.

When you add the `T` before it then it tells make that instead of any file, that rule can only build files that begin with `T`.

The reason make is trying to rebuild the makefile is that GNU make has a special feature that [allows it to remake its own makefiles](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html).  So after it reads its makefile it will try to re-make it.  Normally this has no effect because there's no rule to build a makefile, but here you've added a rule that you've told make can build *anything*.  Adding the `T` keeps the pattern from matching `Makefile` because `Makefile` doesn't begin with `T`.

The simplest thing for you to do is define an explicit rule for the makefile: make always chooses an explicit rule, if it exists, over an implicit rule like a pattern rule:

```
Makefile: ; @:
```

This creates an explicit rule that does nothing (`:` is the shell built-in command that does nothing).

Comment: Now I have: 
`makefile: ; $@:

TESTS=$(shell cat yoursourcefile)
all: $(TESTS)

%: compile_design
compile $@_tb.vhd >> log_file.log
simulate $@`

and I got :
`all_tb.vhd >> log_file.log`
but all_tb.vhd does not exist 
**is it remaking the target all ?**

Comment: I cannot read makefiles in comments, because all newlines are lost.  However, by default (unless you specify differently on the command line) make builds only the first target in the makefile (and all its prerequisites of course).  If you added the rule for `makefile` as the first one, then that's the only thing make will build unless you run `make all`.  Put the makefile rule at the end of the makefile, not the beginning.